# Vuex action/mutation from component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuex

Vue App has a vuex action/mutation which is called from multiple components.

When I look into Vue dev tools, I see the mutation is called multiple times.

Is there any way to know from which component the action/mutation is called?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be helpful for someone in the future but here is my workaround in this cases for Vue 2 with Vuex:

I'm not aware of Vuex providing arguments that can help you backtrack the component that called the mutation but we can always backtrack in the good old fashion way:

1. Adding a console on the mutation, then following that console call in the browser dev console, add a breakpoint, reload the app and step over the function multiple times until you're able to locate the source of the call or at least the next source call
2. Add to your payload argument identifiers from where the calls are being generated, a flag that allows you to identify the file should be enough.

Hope this helps someone later, for big applications it might be more step over clicks than you're expecting but this will definitely work!